# How do I read the lines of a text file into a large string in C?

Tags: c, string, fgets

readtofile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
      /*For File input, I'm copying the lines of the file into a 
       * large string with fgets*/
        FILE *filePtr;

        char buffIter[200];//How much fgets iterates by???
        char *pToken;      //Should hold the large string.

        filePtr = fopen(argv[2],"r");// the filename is passed as the second argument

        while(fgets(bufferIter, 200, filePtr){ ...?

                  filePtr = something?


      /*For File input*/
}
```

I want the above program to read an entire file into a String in C.
I want the filePtr to be that string and if the example.txt looks like:

```
This is a test file.
Here are some strings like cat, dog and mouse.
Escape chars too \n \a \" \b \t.
Specials cases? @ $ % \\ \\\ \\\\ \ \ 
"\\" "\\\" "\"
```

How would the new lines be separated?  Like from "...and mouse. Escape chars..." Would it show up like this in the string if I use fgets as I am?

Thanks.

Comment: `char buffIter[100];` and `fgets(bufferIter, 200, filePtr)` is definitely not good (2nd arg to fgets is `size` aka the number of characters that will be read)

Comment: facepalm*, changed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just read it into a string in one go rather than by-line, e.g.

- fopen the file
- read the length; either

  - fseek to the end; use ftell to get the length then fseek back to the start
  - or fstat the file to get the length
- malloc a new buffer for length + 1
- fread the whole file (i.e. `1, length`) into the buffer
- put a nul in your buffer at the end of the fread (i.e. use the return value of fread not the length)
- fclose

This would give you the raw file data and wouldn't process escapes, etc.